# Где можно прочитать и узнать именно о программном хэшировании?

Tags: хеширование

Здравствуйте, а зачем вообще ввели программное хэширование? Без него не обойтись? В чем его плюсы? Спасибо.

Comment: Немного не понятен вопрос, хэш применяется во многих случаях.

Comment: Вот я не пойму с чем его едят...

Comment: @Alerr - это попытка жестко потролить или вам реально написать "доступный" ответ **специально** для вас?

Comment: Не, ну Вам господа безусловно всё понятно. Если Вам очевидно. то это не значит, что это очевидно всем))) Я не могу понять в чем смысл этого хэширования и его функций, лучшеб ресурс нормальный дали....

Comment: Рискну предположить что вы спрашиваете о програмном хешировании а не о hashcode.ru.

Если так - вам в справку, читаете и поимаете что пометив ваш вопрос меткой `хэшкод` вы (осознанно или нет) указали что вопрос относится именно к ресурсу...

Для меня вопрос выглядел и выглядит примерно так:
****
Зачем вообще нужен **хэшкод**? Без него не обойтись?
****
Вообщем если вы не имели этого введу - отредактируйте ваш вопрос соответствующим образом.

Comment: @Expert - кагбы ответ не принят, не?

Comment: О, теперь вы верно меня поняли...

Comment: Как вы задали вопрос так вас и поняли, в данной ситуации винить можете исключительно себя. 

А понял я что именно вы имели введу исключительно благодаря экстросенсорным способностям

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Википедия хеширование](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Comment: Лично я в основном познакомился с этим вопросом у Кнута в т.3 (Сортировка и поиск).

Comment: Я к тому, что надоели здесь вопросы, на которые ответ - первая ссылка в google или wikipedia. И их становится с каждым днем больше.

Comment: Это не страшно, так и должно быть. Просто новички хотят увидеть советы реальных людей, а не только самые популярные ссылки в поисковике.

Comment: Это да. Но когда видно, что человек задает вопрос, вообще не понимая вопроса. Это значит, что ему просто лень разбираться / читать. Например, этот вопрос. К чему он здесь? Какая от него польза?

Comment: Вообще-то @DUP , Вы правы. 

Вопрос "хеширование" в google уже на первой странице выдал несколько материалов, прочитав которые можно было бы задать здесь более интересные вопросы на данную тему.

Comment: Просто нужно знать с чем имею дело... А по всем этим популярным ссылкам попадается ЕРУНДА!
Пришлось перерыть не мало таких ссылок для осознания что это такое..((( Кстати, я пользуюсь яндексом.

Comment: Я тоже пользуюсь яндексом, но в первую очередь все равно смотрю в википедии для общего понимания, а потом уже смотрю дополнительную литературу.